# JavaScript Pagination Only show 5 buttons

Tags: javascript, button, pagination, hide, show

I have created a pagination system using JavaScript. I have used this code to create the pagination system:

```
function setUpPagination(items, wrapper, rows_per_page) {
  wrapper.innerHTML = "";

  let page_count = Math.ceil(items.length / rows_per_page);
  for (let i = 1; i < page_count + 1; i++) {
    let btn = paginationButton(i, items);
    wrapper.appendChild(btn);
  }
}

function paginationButton(page, items) {
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerText = page;
  if (current_page == page) {
    button.classList.add('active');
  }

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    current_page = page;
    displayList(items, list_element, rows, current_page);

    let current_btn = document.querySelector('.pagination button.active');
    current_btn.classList.remove('active');
    button.classList.add('active');
  })
  return button;
}
```

However, this code shows all of the pagination buttons. If I have 100 pages, all 100 pagination buttons will be shown.

I only want to show 5 buttons at a time. These buttons should be: the page the user is currently on, the 2 pages before the page the user is currently on, the 2 pages after the page the user is currently on.

If the user is on page 1, pages 1 - 5 should be shown.
If the user is on the last page, the last page button and the 4 page buttons before that should be shown.

I have added this code to stop the user from selecting a page which is too high:

```
    if (i >= page_count) {
      i = page_count;
    }
```

However this means the user cannot select the last two pages.
I want to give the user the ability to select the last two pages. However, no extra pages should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return five pages, current in the middle and first/last five if necessary:

```js
const result = getPages(3, 19);
console.log(result);

function getPages(totalPages, currentPage) {
  if (totalPages <= 5) return Array.from(Array(totalPages).keys()).map( r => { return r + 1 });
  let diff = 0;
  const result = [currentPage - 2, currentPage - 1, currentPage, currentPage + 1, currentPage + 2];
  if (result[0] < 3 ) {
    diff = 1 - result[0];
  }
  if (result.slice(-1) > totalPages - 2 ) {
    diff = totalPages - result.slice(-1);
  }
  return result.map( r => { return r + diff });
}
```

Case total 5, current from 1 to 5 returns [1,2,3,4,5].
Case total less than 5, returns an array of number of total length.
Case total 15, current 13, 14 or 15 returns [11,12,13,14,15].

Answer (score 0):

With the way you have set up your for-loop bounds in your `setUpPagination` function, you are iterating over every single page and making a button for each one. I recommend you update the loop bounds to only cover the range of pages you want buttons for.

I envision an update that looks something like this:

```
  for (let i = current_page - 2; i <= current_page + 2; i++) { // <-- HERE!
    let btn = paginationButton(i, items);
    wrapper.appendChild(btn);
  }
}
```

Of note, this won't properly account for when you are looking at the first few or last few pages, so you will want to update this slightly to account for these edge cases (for example, if you are viewing page 1 currently this would attempt to make buttons for pages -1, 0, 1, 2, & 3). I think this should give you a good push in the right direction though!

Comment: How could I ensure the highest page number that can be shown is the final page

Comment: I would compute and store the loop bounds before executing it, like `lowerBound` and `upperBound`. Then for checking at the front of the pages, you could check to see if `current_page - 2` is less than 0, and if so you can directly set `lowerBound` and `upperBound`. For the end of the pages, you can check to see if `current_page + 2` takes you higher than `page_count`. With these changes, your loop would look more like `for (let i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++)`.